# Call PHP API class with defined parameter

Tags: php

I am using this class https://github.com/ricog/coinbase-exchange-php/blob/master/lib/CoinbaseExchange/CoinbaseExchange.php

When I call it using

```
$listOrders = $exchange->listOrders();
print_r($listOrders);
```

This is my output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "d50ec984-77a8-460a-b958-66f114b0de9b",
        "size": "3.0",
        "price": "100.23",
        "product_id": "BTC-USD",
        "status": "open",
        "filled_size": "1.23",
        "fill_fees": "0.001",
        "settled": false,
        "side": "buy",
        "created_at": "2014-11-14 06:39:55.189376+00"
    }
]
```

By default all the pending or open orders are called. The documentation states "To specify multiple statuses, use the status query argument multiple times:
/orders?status=done&status=pending." How can I call the above class where the status is 'done' instead of 'open', without showing any pending transactions.

I tried this `$listOrders = $exchange->listOrders('status'=>'done');`

It didn't work.

Source: https://docs.exchange.coinbase.com/?php#list-orders

Comment: I doesn't seem to be possible to call it with any parameters, not to mention calling it twice with same parameter. Method `listOrders` is not taking any parameters according to source.

Comment: You could just extend class CoinbaseExchange and add custom method listOrders that will create request with uri like this `/orders?status=done&status=pending`.

Answer (score 1):

the class that you are using is not ment for sending multiple params (kind of stupidly written if you ask me). What you can do is to extend that class:

```
class MyExchange extends CoinbaseExchange {
    public function request($endpoint, $params = array()){
        return $response = parent::request($endpoint, $params);
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
$exchange = new MyExchange();
// any other methods required for authentikation and settings like $exchange->auth(...)
$listOrders = $exchange->request('orders', array('status'=>'done', 'status'=>'pending');
```